# XMLDocument VS XmlReader which is more efficient to validate well-formed XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, well-formed

In other words, is XMLDocument more efficient than XmlReader to validate a well formed xml document? from a memory prospective if you have a large XML file and used XMLDocument you might end with out of memory exception.

Comment: `XmlReader` is a low-level streaming API. `XmlDocument` is a higher-level API built on top of `XmlReader`. Use the level which is appropriate: maybe you want an easier-to-use convenient API, or maybe you want to write lots of code to use the more efficient streaming API

Comment: @canton7 that is the answer, I am looking for.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is the answer I was looking for it was provided in a comment by @canton7
XmlReader is a low-level streaming API. XmlDocument is a higher-level API built on top of XmlReader. Using the level which is appropriate: maybe you want an easier-to-use convenient API, or maybe you want to write lots of code to use the more efficient streaming API

Answer (score 0):

To expand on your answer a bit, it depends on what you are trying to do. If this is truly just validating, then XmlDocument is probably the correct version, as it has to complete load to validate. The reader is a "firehose cursor" of sorts that streams the data as you read it. When you have a reader, reading to end will validate. May be a bit faster, but a bit more code.

Comment: why is XmlReader faster than XmlDocument, if it is build on XMLReader as I understood from other comment

Comment: Depends on what you are doing, of course, but a reader can get you to the point you desire and give you the information, rather than read through the entire document. Underneath the hood, .NET uses a flywheel pattern, so it is not that noticeable (probably not something you would worry about unless you were at the Google level?). It is more noticeable with datareader versus things like a dataset (but EF abstracted the hell out of all of this anyway?).